# Is there a command where to see which mysql databses are replicated to slaves?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

We all know, that there are several keys inside the mysql config to control which databases are beeing replicated to slaves. I am wondering if there is a simple mysql command that shows me - based on the my.cnf and all other options that might be set - which databases are really replicated to slaves. I know howto find out, based on bin-log, ignore settings and so on, but a simple mysql command seems not exist - if yes, i hope to find the hidden secret here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS
SHOW MASTER STATUS
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-slave-status.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-master-status.html

Comment: this one way, to find out but the question was: with one single command. "show slave" only shows me "Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table" and "show master" shows me "Binlog_Do_DB" and "Binlog_Ignore_DB" - i always have to use several informations to get a clear picture - the question asks: howto find out with only one single command ;)